# Multiple floats in different divs before clearing

Tags: css, css-float, google-closure

Long story short, I'm utilizing the Closure goog.ui.TabBar base CSS that decorates a div that follows a design pattern. The main "tabBar" div should contain your tab buttons (also divs) that are all floated next to each other. I can't seem to get the content div (below these) to line up. the :after clearing on the closure CSS (included) is clearing on my sidebar instead. Ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/hvMaf/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For good measure, the solution was to add:overflow: hidden; to the #bodycontent container (and remove the margin-left for some browser compatibility issues.

Finished solution: http://jsfiddle.net/hvMaf/7/

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to sort of replicate what I thought you were going for, given your description, but it's a sort of hack, and therefore would not recommend it, [but here it is anyways](http://jsfiddle.net/XGuJy/).  I changed the position of the copyright and increased the content box's size, as well as adding two new rules at the top.  For reference, I did attempt a width of 100%, but it didn't work.